# How to upgrade safely from JSON 1 to JSON 2 wrt utf8 strings?

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

We have a large code base that makes copious use of the JSON v1 API:

```
use JSON;
my $json = objToJson($data);
my $data = jsonToObj($json);
```

We would like to upgrade to JSON v2, so we can start using it in new code, and because we've been encountering other modules that depend on the [v2 API](http://p3rl.org/JSON).

However, if I have stored a utf8-string created by `objToJson()`, it will no longer be decoded in the same way by [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON%3a%3aXS) (which is what JSON v2 uses behind the scenes).

```
use JSON;
use JSON::XS;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $data    = ["\x{263a}b"];
my $encoded = JSON::objToJson($data);
print "different!\n"
  unless JSON::jsonToObj($encoded)->[0] eq JSON::XS::decode_json($encoded)->[0];
print "different!\n"
  unless JSON::jsonToObj($encoded)->[0] eq JSON::XS->new->decode($encoded)->[0];
```

Is there any way for us to upgrade to JSON v2, but still leave around the v1 API for backward compatibility with existing code?

Comment: JSON does not support overloaded comparison and those lines with `==` are not doing what you think they are.  It is simply comparing the memory positions of two different references, which will always be false.  You need to look inside of the array references.  And at that point you should be using `eq` which is the string comparison operator.

Comment: Whoops, thanks Eric. Code corrected (the problem remains the same).

Comment: Is there anything missing from my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules should use a new name when they do drastic changes like that. In this case, the fact that JSON 2.x is mostly a wrapper for JSON::XS conveniently means that's kind what they did.

I recommend:

1. Leave JSON 1.x installed.
2. Install JSON::XS.
3. At your leisure, convert from JSON 1.x to JSON::XS.
4. It's now safe to upgrade to JSON 2.x if you want.

   1. Install JSON 2.x
   2. s/JSON::XS/JSON/g

Comment: ikegami - it's really step 3 that I have a problem with. I don't know how to convert all the uses of JSON 1.x to JSON::XS in our codebase. What I really want is to upgrade to JSON 2.x (since cpanm keeps trying to do this for me :)) but still use the old API exactly as it is existed

Comment: Do it by converting each use, one at a time.

Comment: If I knew what the equivalent of JSON::jsonToObj($encoded) in JSON::XS was, I would use it! But as I pointed out above, JSON::XS::decode_json behaves differently from JSON::jsonToObj when it comes to utf8-encoded strings.

Comment: What's does JSON return for you? (use `{ local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print(Dumper($encoded)); print(Dumper(JSON::jsonToObj($encoded))); }`)

Comment: "[\"\\u263ab\"]"
[ "\342\230\272b"  ]

Comment: Incidentally it seems as if JSON::jsonToObj utf8-encodes any contained scalars, whereas JSON::XS->new->decode does not. At least, I was able to make these equivalent by running rmap_scalar { $_ = encode('utf8', $_) } on the value returned by JSON::XS->new->decode in this example. Don't know if that's the only difference of course.

Comment: Honestly, you're doing it backwards by encoding rather than fixing the code that expects encoded text, but that it indeed about the best you can do to recreate the junk jsonToObj returned.

Comment: I hear you, but this is used in all sorts of code that I didn't write and don't want to have to update or retest, so I just need to duplicate the "junk" as you say. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13489/discussion-between-jonathan-swartz-and-ikegami)